# Laravel Auth Register, Prevent automatic login

Tags: laravel-5

I was developing an app to manage users. I need to access auth/register from logged in users. The default auth redirecting to home page.

It seems after registration, Auth automatically doing ::attempt.

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Could you [show some problematic code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: here is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478303/how-to-disable-auto-login-on-register-in-laravel-5/36628990#36628990) with accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use the `RegistersUsers` (or `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`) trait in your controller you can override the `postRegister` method and simply not log the user in. You can see the original method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L28-L40)

Without logging it that would be:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```