# Disable auto login after Laravel registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I need to disable auto login after registering a new user in a Laravel application.

I have found [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478303/how-to-disable-auto-login-on-register-in-laravel-5) for older versions, but since Laravel 5.4 there is no `AuthController` as it divided to `LoginController` and `RegisterController`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since your `RegisterController` uses `RegistersUsers` trait, all of the trait's methods are available to `RegisterController`. The method you need to override, in order to prevent users to be logged in after they successfully registered is `register()`. Here's the initial body of the method:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

The line: `$this->guard()->login($user);` is where the user gets logged in. You can either remove it or modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @ivanka what is with registered method at the bottom of register method i'm curious coz it uses ternary operator i wonder what's with it and can i change that with just
redirect()->back()->with('info', 'something');

Comment: In the RegisterController also include 
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and `use 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;`

Comment: Sorry but where the hell can I find the default "register" method, that laravel uses without any self-made modifications? Because I've been looking around and I see nothing about it, not even in the documentation.

Comment: @ADHDisDEV Which version of Laravel are you using? More recent versions have separated the auth into two packages: *Laravel Breeze* and *Laravel Jetstream*. If you are using Breeze, it publishes a new controller in your app and you can [remove this line](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/1.x/stubs/default/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php#L47).

Answer (score 2):

I've added `Auth::logout();` next to the guard in the new versions.

```
public function register(Request $request)
   {
   $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

   event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

   \Auth::logout();

   return $this->registered($request, $user)
                ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use default register route you can do it like this...

in `RegistersUsers.php` file

comment this line in `register` function

```
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

I hope this helps you!!

Comment: This answer suggests editing files within the `vendor/` directory, **which should never be done**! Instead you should define a `register()` method in your `AuthController` (or the equivalent) and change accordingly. Refer to the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah. As Ivanka Todorova said, it's not advisable to edit the framework's core files.

Answer (score -4):

You can change the `$redirectTo` `url` in the `RegisterController` to your url.
Or You can override `registered` method of the `RegistersUsers` trait in `RegisterController`.

Comment: redirectTo will bo go to logged page as well