# How can prevent Login after Register, outside of laravel vendor files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authentication

I want to prevent login after registration & I know its very easy & simple. By commenting single line we can do that. But my concern is I don't want to do this in Vendor's file.

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        // $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 - Disable auto login after registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226145/laravel-5-4-disable-auto-login-after-registration)

Comment: Just write this function in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` as per your need.