# How to disable auto login in laravel 8 and redirect to a simple page with success message(after registration)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I dont think so that i am duplicating any question here .
This question is specifically for laravel 8.
I just created the laravel old ways for auth i-e

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

Here is my RegisterController.php

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
   // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required'],
            'city' => ['required'],
            'state' => ['required'],
            'zip' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
          return  User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'zip' => $data['zip'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
       // return redirect()->route('/')->with('success', 'You are successfully Registered!');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to disable auto-login after registration?

Comment: Here is the answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226145/laravel-5-4-disable-auto-login-after-registration

Comment: @kaleemShoukat as i said this question is related to laravel 8 and not for 5.4,things changed too much from 5 to 8

Comment: @Basharmal yes it is clear written in my question

Comment: did you try this ` return redirect()->route('/')->with('success', 'You are successfully Registered!');`

Comment: @basharmal yes bro i tried it but no success ,but again trying for it

Comment: @basharmal brother check the answer i have resolved it,thanks for your kind help

Comment: a pleasure to hear abou it

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have done it using some mix answers at stackover flow for laravel 8.
I am posting it here ,it may help someone in future.

I have overide the method in RegisterController.php like this and redirected to a page with success message

used theses namespaces in use RegisterController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
```

and then added this in RegisterController.php at bottom

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        return $this->registered($request, $user)
           // ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
          ?: redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'You are successfully Registered!');
    }
```

Tip:dont override this method directly in vendor area.
As this type of answer was somewhere but mixed and confused so i have written it very clearly.
Thanks every one for their cooperation