# How can I disable auto login after registration in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel

I installed latest Laravel 9 Framework, but it's really changed from 8.

I want to activate manually the users after registration so I want to stop autologin after user registration but I cannot understand what I need to change to stop this autologin.
The only way seems to be create a new registration page with a new controller....
do you know if there are other ways?

Thanks in advance
Dierre

Comment: see solution to related issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73493357/16723209

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Disable auto login after registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226145/laravel-5-4-disable-auto-login-after-registration)

Answer (score 1):

Change redirect to in RegisterController.php (path: app/Http/Controllers/Auth).

```
protected $redirectTo = '/your url';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the file App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.

Change the snippet:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

For:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Thus, the "register" route is no longer public and will only be accessed after the change, by anyone who is already logged into the system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).